# How to pass the result of a function call to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I declared a function on my scope that return an object.
I try to pass the result of this function to a custom directive, but it triggers an infinite digest loop (open your console and run the snippet).

It seems that the `objectEquality` flag is not set on the watcher and that's why angular is not performing a deep comparison.

What am I doing wrong ? Is it even possible to achieve or am I going against Angular principles ?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bar = function() {
    return {
      baz: 'qux'
    };
  };
}).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      foo: '='
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-directive foo="bar()"></my-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you need this to be a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using one-way binding (`&`) instead. That will attach a getter function to your directive scope, you can use that function to get the result of the `bar` function.

See below:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bar = function() {
    return {
      baz: 'qux'
    };
  };
}).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      foo: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope){
      console.log(scope.foo())
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-directive foo="bar()"></my-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll never get used to it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you pass your scope through function you have to use '&'

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bar = function() {
    return {
      baz: 'qux'
    };
  };
}).directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      foo: '&'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <my-directive foo="bar()"></my-directive>
  </div>
</div>
```